# How to check if person has a specfic role then return True or False in a embed

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm currently making a Discord Bot for my Discord Server, and what I'm wanting to do is make a User Information Embed, I've got the embed created, but what I'm wanting to do is like if the user has the Premium Role, then in the embed it'll say like "True" or "False" if they don't have the role.

here's my Embed Code:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "info")) {
message.delete(500)
const userinfo = new Discord.RichEmbed()
 .setColor('#71ff33')
 .setTitle('')
 .setURL('')
 .setAuthor('User Information', 'http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/585e4bf3cb11b227491c339a.png')
 .setDescription("Hey " + message.author.username + " here's the information you requested.")
 .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
 .addBlankField()
 .addField('**User:**', message.member.user, true)
  .addField('**Rank:**', message.member.highestRole, true)
  .addField('**Joined:**', message.member.joinedAt, true)
  .addField('**Premium:**', , true) //This is where I'm stuck at.
  .setImage()
  .addBlankField()
  .setTimestamp()
 .setFooter('Discord User Information' , message.author.avatarURL);
  message.channel.send(userinfo);  
}
```

Right there at the Premium field, I want it to display 'True' or 'False' depending if they got the role or not, if I'm making sense on what I'm trying to explain here.

I'm using Node.Js and Discord.Js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use one of the following options

This returns true/false

```js
message.member.roles.some(r => r.name === 'Premium');
```

These return the role if found. Meaning additional logic is required to determine true or false based on if a role is returned or not.

```js
message.member.roles.get(id);
message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Premium');
message.member.roles.find(r => r.id === id); //the .get(id) is faster
```

Comment: In the embed you could use a nested template literal and check if a role was found using the options above, i.e. `\`${message.member.roles.get(id) ? 'True' : 'False'}\``